# Creating a view and selecting Top10

Tags: sql-server

So the title is pretty accurate I think I am almost there here is what I have

Edit: The view is supposed to select the column vendorname,a column LastInvoice which is the latest date in the column and the total of the invoiceTotal column. I want this to display only the top 10 paid invoiceTotals and the corresponding latest Invoice Date and Vendor Name.

```
CREATE VIEW TOP10PAIDInvoices
AS
  SELECT VendorName,
         MAX(InvoiceDate)  AS LastInvoice,
         SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS SumOfInvoices
  FROM   Vendors
         JOIN Invoices
           ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
  WHERE  (SELECT TOP 10 SumOfInvoices
          FROM   TOP10PAIDInvoices
          GROUP  BY SumOfInvoices
          HAVING SumOfInvoices > 0)
  ORDER  BY SumOfInvoices
```

Comment: please describe the problem you're having

Comment: Instead of just giving us the broken query please explain what is supposed to be doing. I have no idea what the recursive `TOP10PAIDInvoices` reference is meant to be about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, in part because your view def is attempting a self-reference.

`ORDER BY` is legal in a view def when used in conjunction with a TOP N expression.

```
CREATE VIEW TOP10PAIDInvoices AS
SELECT TOP 10 VendorName = MAX(VendorName), MAX(InvoiceDate) AS LastInvoice, SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS SumOfInvoices
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
GROUP BY Vendors.VendorID
HAVING SUM(InvoiceTotal) > 0
ORDER BY SUM(InvoiceTotal) DESC;
GO
```

Comment: From what I can tell I was missing the Group By and the Go, never heard of the Go part but I always have trouble with group by. I did have something very very close to this just without the group by and go that is. I searched and found another question about having top10 and it showed the nested select statement.

Comment: GO is actually a preprocessor batch command for SSMS and not technically part of SQL. It's usually optional, but I included it here out of habit more than anything else.